# SLComposeViewController : Does it handle FaceBook API Upgrade commencing on may 2015?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, social-framework, slcomposeviewcontroller

Facebook api is upgraded. Hence v2.x api calls are no more valid from april 30th 2015. I'm using `SLComposeViewController` in my app. Does this changes by Facebook  will affect my app? Is it safe to continue using `SLComposeViewController`? Please do suggest.

Comment: I have no issues using the latest one we can use SLComposeViewController

Comment: Right now even we can use facebook sdk and  login and share is allowed in facebook sdk now . It will be deprecated after april 30th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the API Apple uses with Facebook, regardless of what its internal implementation details are, will continue to function, as per the agreement between Apple and Facebook.
To be sure, you should [contact Apple Developer Relation support](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/submit/) and consult with them.